# Conflict bewteen OLEObjects and Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete an ActiveX `OLEObject` from a sheet and then launch a `UserForm` as `vbModeLess`.

In the code below:

First, a sub creates a `OLEObject` (a `Label`) in sheet "mySheet" with its caption and name.

```
Sub creteOleo()

    Dim rng As Range
            
    Set rng = Sheets("mySheet").Range("B2:C3")
            
    With Sheets("mySheet").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", _
                                            Link:=False, _
                                            DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                            Left:=rng.Left, _
                                            Top:=rng.Top, _
                                            Width:=rng.Width, _
                                            Height:=rng.Height)
        .Name = "myOleo" 'A name
        .Object.Font.Size = 13
        .Object.Caption = "test"
    End With
End Sub
```

Then a sub that deletes it, then launches a UserForm (the UserForm  just contains a label, it's for testing so there is no code inside) with `vbModeLess` state.

```
Sub deleteOleo()
    Sheets("mySheet").OLEObjects("myOleo").Delete
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Here is the problem, deleting a specific OLEObject then launching the UserForm deletes the OLEObject as expected but then the UserForm appears for a brief moment before disappearing.

This problem only appears when UserForm is launched in `vbModeLess` state, so I went for another way (hiding the object instead of deleting it) that works, but I am curious to know why VBA behaves that way.

My understanding is that since Excel executes the `UserForm1.Show` after finishing deleting the `OLEObject`, it shouldn't interfere with it. Moreover, it isn't like if I was deleting all objects, but just a specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is an undocumented bug (At least I never did find any documentation around it). Having said that you can achieve what you want by doing the following.

**Logic**

1. Show the form in `Modal`
2. In `UserForm_Activate()` event change it back to `Modeless`.

**In a Module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub creteOleo()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheets("mySheet").Range("B2:C3")
    
    With Sheets("mySheet").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", _
                                          Link:=False, _
                                          DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                          Left:=rng.Left, _
                                          Top:=rng.Top, _
                                          Width:=rng.Width, _
                                          Height:=rng.Height)
                                          
        .Name = "myOleo" 'On lui donne un nom
        .Object.Font.Size = 13
        .Object.Caption = "test"
    End With
End Sub

Sub deleteOleo()
    Sheets("mySheet").OLEObjects("myOleo").Delete
    
    DoEvents
    
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

**In the Userform Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function EnableWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    EnableWindow GetParent(FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)), 1
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: It is interesting that even after all these years of VBA being the default language for using macros in excel, there are still strange bugs like that. Anyway, thanks for the very detailed explanation, I appreciate it!